# express DELETE route acting strange? Unexpected token 'n'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the delete route:

```
router.delete('/users/:name' , function (req, res, next) {
    User.deleteOne({name: req.params.name}).then (function (user) {
        console.log('DELETED / ', req.params.name);
        res.send('DELETED / ', req.params.name);
    }).catch (next)
});
```

the `router.get` and `router.post` under the same '/users/' work no problem.

I get a strange error when I try this,

```
{
    "error": "Unexpected token n in JSON at position 3"
}
```

although I have a 200 OK status response. Any idea what is going on? I'm trying in postman.

UPDATE:

Lesson learned here. Make sure your testing methods are in fact *correct*.

I was sending a different header that somehow got mixed up in postman which causes errors. It was a hard to notice at first but clicking the setting I discovered there as a strange extra huge JSON batch being sent back. Even though at first glance everything seemed *ok*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
router.delete('/users/:name' , function (req, res) {
    User.deleteOne({name: req.params.name})
    .exec()
    .catch (err => res.status(500).send(err) )
    .then (function () {
        console.log('DELETED / ', req.params.name);
        res.send('DELETED / ', req.params.name);
    })
});
```

Comment: I edited your answer, the `then` method never pass an error object. If there is any error, it will be passed to the next `catch` method

Comment: same error, nothing changed. To confirm, I'm using POSTMAN; changed the method to DELETE and the url I am using is 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/Test' and there is 100% a test users with a name parameter Test. I'm assuming because I didn't receive the 500 status that I'm not hitting the route?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Express API reference of res.send()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send):

> When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation

Your code above seems to send the string `"DELETED / "` back. Maybe that is the reason why your JS code raise JSON parse error.

Try replace `res.send` statement with this one below:

```
res.send({msg : 'DELETED / ', user: req.params.name});
```

Hope this helps.